# Remove elements after an item in a list, jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Here's  my question:

I have a list of  elements contained within a main container like so:

```
<span class="main_container">
    <span id=".." class=".." position="1"...> </span>
    <span id=".." class=".." position="2"...> </span>  
    <span id=".." class=".." position="3"...> </span>
    <span id=".." class=".." position="4"...> </span>
    <span id=".." class=".." position="5"...> </span>
    <span id=".." class=".." position="6"...> </span>
</span>
```

I use the ID and position for different purposes. Now, when I click let's say on element at position 4, I want the system to delete  span 4, and all the ones below it. i.e 5, 6.

How do I do this is jQuery? I tried `.parents()` but that didn't do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use this:

http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

```
$('.main_container').find('span').click(function(){
  var jq_this = $(this);
  jq_this.nextAll().remove();  // remove all later siblings
  jq_this.remove();            // removes self
});
```

Comment: Or `$(this).nextAll().remove().end().remove();`

Comment: or `$(this).nextAll().add(this).remove();` ;p (Always several ways of skinning the cat)

Answer (score 1):

Bind [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on the child spans, use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get its sequence index, then use [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector to find elements past it and use [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$('.main_container span').click(function(){
    // get position of current element
    var index = $(this).index();
    // delete this and all elements past this element
    $(this).parent().find('span:gt('+index+')').add(this).remove();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cDZqk/

You can also use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) if there's more nesting going on:

```
$('.main_container span').click(function(){
    // get position of current element
    var index = $(this).index();
    // delete this and all elements past this element
    $(this).parent().children(':gt('+index+')').add(this).remove();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cDZqk/1/

*or, ya know, you can use `.nextAll` and let it take care of it for you. **:curses:***

The "one-liner" version of BYossarian's answer:

```
$('.main_container span').click(function(){
    $(this).nextAll().add(this).remove();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cDZqk/2/